# using namespace in template class member functions defined in header file

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I am new to C++ but as I understand it is bad to use the `using namespace` keywords in header files. I am trying to write a template class, and have read that the definition of the template class member functions must be in the header as well as all the template code must be in the same place. My issue is, it can get tedious writing all of the code without the `using namespace` keywords. For example at the moment I have:

```
#ifndef RANDOMTREE_H_
#define RANDOMTREE_H_

template<class T>
class RandomTree {
private:
    typedef double (*funcion_ptr) (T, T);
public:
    RandomTree(std::vector<T> data, std::vector<funcion_ptr>){
        ...
    }
    void train_tree();
};

#endif /* RANDOMTREE_H_ */
```

But I intend to use some boost methods etc inside the function bodies and would like to know if there is a way to not have to keep typing the prefixes `std::` and `boost::`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this code looks pretty good to me.

It's not a big deal to write them once in the declarations.

In the definitions, if you want to omit writing `ns::`, you may have `using namespace ns;` *inside a function*.

Or, just include some names, like: `using ns::name;`. But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Aly - because if I read someone else's code, I'd like to know which names (he/she uses) - from which namespace they come. Suppose you have a lot of general names like `String`, or `Thread`, or `Pipe`, etc. - it's good to know their namespaces, especially in big projects - all these names could have been defined in `boost`, in `std`, in some other lib, or just to be local for the current project.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use typedef:

`typedef std::string string;`

It has the advantage not using `using`

Answer (score 1):

The options to not having to type the qualifications (`std::`, `boost::`) **is** having `using` directives. If there was any other way (there isn't in this case), it would carry around the same problem as having the `using` directives, so either alternative would be equally bad.

Note that `using` doesn't have to be applied to a namespace. You can, for example, do:

```
using std::string;
```

and then directly use `string`, but this also isn't recommended.

Comment: ok, just to be clear: as far as template classes go, I am constrained to implement the member functions inside the header file, which then adds the constraint of not using the using directive?

Comment: @Aly yes. There's no constraint per-say against using directives, it's just frowned upon. I'd just keep the qualifications.